# convert csv data to dict without writing file to disk

Tags: python, csv, unzip

Here is my scenario: I have a zip file that I am downloading with `requests` into memory rather than writing a file. I am unzipping the data into an object called `myzipfile`. Inside the zip file is a csv file. I would like to convert each row of the csv data into a dictionary. Here is what I have so far.

```
import csv
from io import BytesIO
import requests

# other imports etc. 

        r = requests.get(url=fileurl, headers=headers, stream=True)
        filebytes = BytesIO(r.content)

        myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)
        for name in myzipfile.namelist():  
            mycsv = myzipfile.open(name).read()
            for row in csv.DictReader(mycsv):  # it fails here.
                print(row)
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Looks like `csv.DictReader(mycsv)` expects a file object instead of raw data. How do I convert the rows in the `mycsv` object data `(<class 'bytes'>)` to a list of dictionaries? I'm trying to accomplish this without writing a file to disk and working directly from csv objects in memory.

Comment: wouldn't it just be `csv.DictReader(myzipfile.open(name))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DictReader` expects a file or file-like object: we can satisfy this expectation by loading the zipped file into an `io.StringIO` instance.

Note that `StringIO` expects its argument to be a `str`, but reading a file from the zipfile returns `bytes`, so the data must be decoded.  This example assumes that the csv was originally encoded with the local system's default encoding.  If that is not the case the correct encoding must be passed to `decode()`.

```
for name in myzipfile.namelist():
    data = myzipfile.open(name).read().decode()
    mycsv = io.StringIO(data)
    reader = csv.DictReader(mycsv)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_list = [] # a list
reader = csv.DictReader(open('yourfile.csv', 'rb'))
for line in reader: # since we used DictReader, each line will be saved as a dictionary
 dict_list.append(line)
```

Comment: trying to do this without writing a file to disk. is it possible?

Comment: I believe you are reading the file in your code as well, that's the same thing I am doing here.